# Variation w.r.t. metric of electromagnetic tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, general-relativity, metric-tensor, variational-calculus

In this link  https://www.theoretical-physics.net/dev/relativity/fields.html#equation-stress-energy-tensors they state that:

> $$ \frac{\delta (F_{\alpha\beta} F^{\alpha\beta} )}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} = \delta (g^{\alpha \lambda} g^{\beta \rho}) F_{\alpha \beta} F_{\lambda \rho} = 2 \delta (g^{\alpha \lambda}) g^{\beta \rho} F_{\alpha \beta} F_{\lambda \rho} = 2\delta (g^{\alpha \lambda})F_{\alpha \beta}{F_{\lambda}}^{\beta}.$$

How do I prove this?

Edit:

$$\delta (g^{\alpha \lambda} g^{\beta \rho}) F_{\alpha \beta} F_{\lambda \rho} \\ = \delta (g^{\alpha \lambda})g^{\beta \rho} F_{\alpha \beta} F_{\lambda \rho} + g^{\alpha \lambda} \delta (g^{\beta \rho}) F_{\alpha \beta} F_{\lambda \rho} \\
$$
Renaming indices in the second term $\alpha \rightarrow \beta $ , $\lambda\rightarrow \rho$ , $\beta \rightarrow \alpha$ and $\rho\rightarrow \lambda$:

$$g^{\alpha \lambda} \delta (g^{\beta \rho}) F_{\alpha \beta} F_{\lambda \rho} \\
=g^{\beta \rho} \delta (g^{\alpha \lambda}) F_{\beta \alpha} F_{\rho \lambda} \\
= g^{\beta \rho} \delta (g^{\alpha \lambda}) [-F_{\alpha \beta }] [-F_{\lambda \rho  }] \\
= g^{\beta \rho} \delta (g^{\alpha \lambda}) F_{\alpha \beta } F_{\lambda \rho} $$

Is this correct?

If so, I can conclude:

$$\delta (g^{\alpha \lambda} g^{\beta \rho}) F_{\alpha \beta} F_{\lambda \rho} = \delta (g^{\alpha \lambda})g^{\beta \rho} F_{\alpha \beta} F_{\lambda \rho} + g^{\beta \rho} \delta (g^{\alpha \lambda}) F_{\alpha \beta } F_{\lambda \rho} = 2\delta (g^{\alpha \lambda})F_{\alpha \beta}{F_{\lambda}}^{\beta} \\$$

Comment: Which of the three equalities don’t you understand?

Comment: The third inequality( $ \delta (g^{\alpha \lambda} g^{\beta \rho}) F_{\alpha \beta} F_{\lambda \rho} = 2 \delta (g^{\alpha \lambda}) g^{\beta \rho} F_{\alpha \beta} F_{\lambda \rho}$ )

Comment: @RFeynman Variation distributes like a derivative would do. Rearrange the indices and you get the result.

Comment: @DavidMorgante I tried and I'm not getting the same result, I might be doing something wrong. Could you show your proof please?

Comment: Vary each of the two factors using the product rule. In the second term, relabel indices and use antisymmetry of $F$ to show it is equal to the first.

Comment: Im going to show you my work

Comment: @G.Smith can you confirm?